# Photoshop Rounding Transform Dimensions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform, dimensions

What I really like about Illustrator is the ability to mathematically resize objects. In Photoshop you can input the desired dimensions of an object which is good enough more often than not. I was just trying to input these pixel dimensions, W = 195.06px; H = 212.77, *without* maintaining the aspect ratio. After confirming the transformation I went to double check the entries and Photoshop rounded them to W = 195.00px; H = 213.00px.

The object I am working with is a shape that is used to a accent a design element. I got the dimensions from another instance of the same object and was trying to make them exactly the same but when I try to edit them it rounds up.

The resulting difference between dimensions is impossible to notice but why is Photoshop rounding the dimensions? I can't figure this out for the life of me and can provide screenshots if requested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop has allways image size in whole pixels as your computer screen, too. Illustrator can internally have any sizes, but surely everything is finally shown as pixels.

Comment: Illustrator does not have a fixed pixel grid, so size of pixels depends on your view

Comment: Please see the edit I made on the original post after seeing your comment!

Comment: @Trevor Was the another instance in Photoshop? How did you see that the height of that another instance was  212.77 pixels and confirmed that the unit really was pixels, not something nearly in the same way written? I'm interested to see a screenshot. I have never succeeded to see  any other than integer widths and heights in Photoshop, if I had set in preferences the used unit to be px, not even when copied a 11,5 px wide vector shape from Illustrator. It was rounded instantly.

Comment: Yeah it was in Photoshop. They are a shape behind a smart object to make it look its moving so I was trying to make sure the two that appeared to be in the foreground most were exactly the same. At this point I have accepted it for what it is